# Ruby on Rails delete format JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I'm trying to delete a row from the table by JSON.
The delete button is as follows:

```
link_to('Delete', product, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, remote: true)
```

controller:

```
  def destroy
    @product.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

When I press the button, the record is deleted, but an error in the console:

**ActionView::MissingTemplate Missing template products/destroy**

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: It is trying to render your destroy.html  template, but can not find it. I suggest you render your (most likely) index action afterwards to see the changes in effect. Something like: `render: "index" ` should do the job.

Comment: Please post the full error message

Comment: Yes, it works! But why do we need to render this page? I would simply delete the entries, and then dynamically refresh the page java script.

Comment: You are sending the delete action via HTML so it's going to trigger a html response. Why do you want to delete it "by JSON"?

Comment: Okay, so my job, I use datatables, I want by pressing the "Delete" page is not updated, and simply delete the entry, and then updated datatables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 def destroy
    @product.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to home_path, notice: 'Article was successfully destroyed' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

You should redirect to other page if product was deleted.